# Can undefined variables and notices cause a cpu spike?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mysql, php, lamp

We're running centos 6.7, PHP 5 and MySQL 5.5 and Apache 2.2.15. Sometimes we see high CPU usage, mainly caused by MySQL so we take all the logs we can get. We're addressing MySQL optimization separately, this question is about PHP and apache mainly.

In apache error log, we keep seeing undefined variables, notices, and warnings. Every few thousand requests or more apache seems to restart.

Two questions:

- Do Apache errors cause apache to restart at some point?
- Do they cause high CPU usage, at some point?

The error log can be found [here](https://filebin.net/xt7vkn8ezqqy1vng), will expire in a week.

I found a strange entry

[image]

Not sure what Microsoft's IIS has to do with the log file.

Comment: Please add to your question the exact log messages in question. httpd processes restarting can range from benign intentional `MaxRequestsPerChild ` limits to crashing and dying.

Comment: Show us lines 12788 and 4221.

Answer (score 0):

Install debug symbols for this software stack and run `perf top`. This provides the top symbols by on-CPU sampling, so you can find the active functions.

Complicating this, I don't know how good perf is on that older kernel. In fact, CentOS 5 has been end of life since March 2017. The only answer to getting meaningful fixes is to upgrade.

Comment: Uploading the log file, will let you know when it's done, we use centos 6.7 not 5, sorry.

Comment: In theory, a handful of log lines before and after a "restart" will be sufficient. `perf top` is a different thing. When watching it you may see spikes, usually the top 5 or so symbols use the most CPU.

Comment: I added the log file to the question